# Pooling methods after multiple imputation

Tags: multiple-imputation

I am a biginner for multiple imputation. Now trying pool all the results, but wondering how to do so. I need to make a table for number of patietns in each categories, percentage, and OR and 95%CI for it. I couldn't find any code in R, Do I have to do with rubin;s rule manually?

Detail
Building a prediction model with one binary outcome and multiple predictors. Want to show number of patients and percentage for each outcome categories by predictors. But after MI, those number are different from 5 imputed dataset.

Comment: I would recommend using software to do that for you. eg `mice` in r, `statsmodels` in python. see https://bookdown.org/mwheymans/bookmi/rubins-rules.html to implement yourself

Comment: Don't know what takeaways you had from Rubin's book but, having taken a class with him on imputation, I came away with a few of his suggestions. 1) Missing at random is the best mechanism on which to base MI. 2) Build a separate imputation model for each feature, ranked from least to most MVs. 3) Include the full information from previous MI models in current models. 4) Include the dependent variable in all models but don't impute the DV. 5) The goal of each successive model is to maintain the means and SDs of the unimputed data. 6) Features with huge %s of MVs are problematic